# Query for each element

Tags: sql

I am given the following database schema

```
donuts (name: string, price: integer) 
grocery (no: string, gname: string, minCredit: integer) 
distributor (dname: string, gno: string, purchaseYear: integer)
```

For each year (distributor.purchaseYear), the grocery "VONS" purchased atleast one donut, find the number of donuts purchased. The output be set of tuples, which indicates the year and the number of donuts purchased by "VONS"

I am not sure how to approach this. I tried

```
 SELECT (d.purchaseYear, COUNT(dd.name))
 FROM distributor d, donut dd, grocery g
 WHERE g.name = "VONS"
```

This seems to give me the incorrect output.

Comment: in your schema how is grocery vons keeping record of purchases

Comment: which table hold the transaction data of donuts purchased? and how these tables are connected ?

Comment: No join conditions? You'll get a lot of rows returned...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a schema as below

```
donuts (gname: string, price: integer, purchaseYear: integer) // record for every donut purchased by the grocery gname in the year
grocery (gno: string, gname: string, minCredit: integer)  // grocery details
distributor (dname: string, gno: string, purchaseYear: integer) // distributor details
```

You can get the data with the below query

```
select 
        g.name
      , d.purchaseyear
      , count(do.gname)
from distributor d
join grocery g on g.gno = d.gno
join donuts do on do.gname = g.gname
where g.name = 'VONS'
group by g.name, d.purchaseyear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using totally separated tables, it won't work. Consider using `foreign keys` and `joins` to get informations from different tables, but related with each other `on` one or more particular field.